# How to configure CentOS 6 as a Proxy Server

Tags: centos, proxy

I have installed new server with CentOS 6. How do I configure it to become a Proxy Server?

Comment: Proxy for what? HTTP? SMTP? General network gateway/VPN/whatever?

Comment: @natra Isn't it the answer you want?

Answer (score 5):

visit these pages, all you need is described there:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-rhel-centos-fedora-squid-installation-configuration.html

http://www.php2s.com/linux/install-configure-squid-proxy-server-on-centos-or-enterprise-linux-5-and-implement-access-control-list-to-block-website.html

but if you want to have extensive understanding of all aspects of configuring proxy server (here: squid) its better to read one following books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Squid-Proxy-Server-3-1-Beginners/dp/1849513902/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1335773355&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849513902)

[http://www.amazon.com/Fedora-Networking-Servers-Richard-Petersen/dp/1936280191/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1335773355&sr=1-6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936280191)

(the latter is for Fedora but there is no fundamental deference between it and CentOS in this field )